# Weird behavior of Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal: values are off by ~28 pixels

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to detect if a user clicked on an `ImageSpan`. I use `Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(offset)` to get the position of `ImageSpan` within the `TextView` but get a value which is off by approximately -28 pixels.

Here is the simplified code:

```java
SpannableStringBuilder result = new SpannableStringBuilder();

// Insert Play icon
Drawable play = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.ic_play);
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(play, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
final Rect bounds = span.getDrawable().getBounds();
result.append(" ", span, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

result.append(" x "); // The "x" is just for illustrative purposes.

// Insert waveform.
WaveDrawable dw = new WaveDrawable(new Rect(0, 0, (int) width, (int) (bounds.height() * 0.9f)));
ImageSpan wave = new ImageSpan(dw, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
result.append(new SpannableStringBuilder().append(" ", wave, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE), new ClickableSpan() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
          TextView tv = (TextView) widget;
          Layout tvl = tv.getLayout();
          Spanned fullText = (Spanned) tv.getText();
          float startX = tvl.getPrimaryHorizontal(fullText.getSpanStart(wave));
          float endX = tvl.getPrimaryHorizontal(fullText.getSpanEnd(wave));
          Log.i(TAG, "Waveform clicked! start=" + startX +
                            "; end=" + endX +
                            "; width=" + (endX - startX) +
                            "; TextView width=" + widget.getWidth() +
                            "; drawable width=" + dw.getBounds().width());
     }
}, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

The logcat output is

`Waveform clicked! start=138.0; end=567.0; width=429.0; TextView width=601; drawable width=429`

The values `start=138.0; end=567.0` are definitely wrong, they should be around `start=166.0; end=595.0;`

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

The thin red box is the boundary of the drawable. The white background is the `TextView`. It's very obvious from the picture that the space between the right edges of the drawable and the TextView is around 6 pixels, not 601-567 = 34 pixels like `getPrimaryHorizontal` returns. For scale: the size of the Play button is 99 pixels.

If I use the same approach to get the position of the Play ImageSpan I get correct result.

Is this an Android bug or my bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out: the TextView had padding. Layout coordinates do not account for padding, while TextView coordinates do.